# Grid Search in SVM not at all improving the model

Tags: machine-learning

I want my SVM to classify the given data into three classes 0,1,2. Initially i'm getting 0 prediction in class 1. So i used Grid search and even after using grid search, class 1 is getting 0.0 precision. What might be wrong? How can i make my model more precise?

before grid search:

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.75      0.44      0.55        41
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00        37
           2       0.50      0.98      0.66        55

    accuracy                           0.54       133
   macro avg       0.42      0.47      0.40       133
weighted avg       0.44      0.54      0.44       133
```

after grid search: {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.1, 'kernel': 'rbf'}

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.72      0.56      0.63        41
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00        37
           2       0.52      0.96      0.68        55

    accuracy                           0.57       133
   macro avg       0.41      0.51      0.44       133
weighted avg       0.44      0.57      0.48       133
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the plot, it seems that the data is linearly separable with high amount of noise. In this case you can use `linear` kernel of SVM.